# Injection of monomials of countable variables on $C(S^1)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials, fourier-analysis

Denote Mon$_\infty \subseteq \mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,...]$ the set of monomials on a countable number of variables, that is, elements of the form
$$
z_{i_1}^{k_1}z_{i_2}^{k_2}...z_{i_n}^{k_n},
$$
where each $i_j,k_j \in \mathbb N$.

My question is if there is an injective map Mon$_\infty \rightarrow C(S^1)$, that to each monomial assigns a continuous function on the unit circle $S^1 \subseteq \mathbb C$.

Im thinking things analogous to Fourier Transform or other integral/sum transforms.

If necessary, the target space can be enlarged to $L^2(S^1)$.

Comment: $z_1^{k_1}z_2^{k_2}z_3^{k_3}\dotsm$, where only finitely many of the $k_i$ are non-zero, could be sent to $z\mapsto z^{p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}p_3^{k_3}\dotsm}$, where $p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots$ is an enumeration of all the primes.

Comment: @NDB Thank you so much! I have a following question, does this injection prove that $$C\left( \prod\limits_{n \in \mathbb N} S^1 \right) \cong C(S^1)?$$ Since the monomials on a countable number of variables generate the first one as a C*-algebra and the monomials on one variable generate $C(S^1)$ (these follow from the Stone-Wiestrass theorem). I know this cannot be true due to Gelfand duality, so my real question is: Why does this injection does not provide a C*-algebra isomorphism?

Comment: Why the monomials generate the first one? That doesn't sound right. Imagine for each subset $I$ of the natural numbers, you take a function that makes a bump of size $1$ near the point with angle $0$ for all coordinates in $I$, zero otherwise, and constant with respect to the coordinates not in $I$. Those functions are distance $1$ from each other. So, the first space is not separable.

Comment: @NDB Thank you so much for your replies. They generate the first space since the *-algebra generated by the monomials contains the constant functions and separates points, thus it is dense. I think the problem lies in the fact that the injection described does not induce an algebra homomorphsim.